# Deserialze "Catch All" variant in tagged enum

Tags: rust, enums, serde

I am deserializing a bunch of documents into an enum. My documents have a field that can be used to pick the correct variant. I want the following three points to happen:

1. if the tag matches one of the Variant, deserialize it into this variant
2. if the tag doesn't match , deserialize it into the `Other` variant.
3. if the tag matches but the content doesn't match the defined structure, panic.

I have tried the few following solutions but didn't manage to achieve all three points:

Just `#[serde(other)]`

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Document {
   Config {
      path: PathBuf,
   },
   #[serde(other)]
   Other,
}
```

With this, the content of the document is not deserialized if it doesn't match `Config`.

Untagged enum:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Document {
   Config {
      type: String,
      path: PathBuf,
   },
   Other(serde_yaml::Value),
}
```

With this one I get the content of documents that don't match as a `Value`. Unfortunately if somebody write a file of `type: Config` with a typo like say `paht: /etc/`, it will result in being deserialized as Other instead of panicking.

Finally, with a nested enum:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Document {
   Config(Config),
   Other(serde_yaml::Value),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Config {
   path: PathBuf,
}
```

This seems to behave exactly like the previous case (simple untagged enum).

How can I get both `Other` deserialized as a `serde_yaml::Value` when nothing matches and panicking if the tag matches but not the content of the structure?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make the path parameter optional, so that the Config enum variant is used whenever the file contains `type:Config`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Document {
    Config(Config),
    Other(serde_yaml::Value),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
struct Config {
    path: Option<PathBuf>,
}

fn main() {
    const CONFIG_OK: &str = "type: Config\npath: /etc/passwd";
    let doc: Document = serde_yaml::from_str(CONFIG_OK).unwrap();
    println!("{doc:?}");
    //Config(Config { path: Some("/etc/passwd") })

    const CONFIG_BAD: &str = "type: Config\npaht: /etc/passwd";
    let doc: Document = serde_yaml::from_str(CONFIG_BAD).unwrap();
    println!("{doc:?}");
    //Config(Config { path: None })

    const OTHER: &str = "type: Other\nkey: value";
    let doc: Document = serde_yaml::from_str(OTHER).unwrap();
    println!("{doc:?}");
    //Other(Mapping {"key": String("value")})
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Having a tag on Document means that you need to add `serde(other)` on `Other` which would need to be a unit type and won't be deserialized.